# x86 assembly - Using binary number to index into list

Tags: assembly, x86

I have this list:

```
list    db ' ETA'
```

and I have a variable, index, containing '010' (binary 2)  I want to index 2 places into the list using index (which represents 2).  I have si pointing to list but when I try this:

```
         mov  al,[si+index]
```

It indexes to the wrong value because, i believe, it thinks index represents a hex number (16) instead of a binary number (2).  I think this because I inserted '2' instead of 'index' and al contained 'T' which is what I want. Is this what is happening? and how can I avoid it?

Comment: No, that's not what is happening. A numerical value in computer is numerical value, it's not binary, hexa or decimal, that's presentation of value. So when "+index" is calculated, the value of index is taken, which is probably address of memory, and not content of memory (you expect?). Either way, it has nothing to do with the formatting of values.

Comment: Split the instruction : `mov index,010b` (notice the "b" after "010") , `add si,index` , `mov al,[si]`. Index must be of type `DW` (word).

Answer (score 3):

To give you idea what I mean by presentation and value:

```
mov  ax,12345  ; load register "ax" with value 12345
```

Now what is in `ax`? A value. Value, which humans present usually in decimal formatting as `12345`. But it is also the same value, which can be printed as `0x3039` in hexadecimal formatting, or `0011 0000 0011 1001` in binary formatting. Or it can be printed as two character long ASCII string shown as `"90"` (word `0x3039` is in bytes: `0x39 0x30` on little-endian system, `0x39` equals char `'9'`, `0x30` equals char `'0'` in ASCII encoding). When displayed as RGB colour pixel, it will be very dark yellow (if R = 0x39, G = 0x30, B = 0x00). When played as sound, it will be probably not audible by human (too short to form sample data).

Neither of these "presentations" of ax value are how the computer "sees" it. Computer has different levels of electrical current in 16 cells/bits (sort of wires) allocated as "ax" for the CPU.

Actually for most of the instructions it doesn't even know we associate particular cell (bit) with particular power-of-two value (ie. 1001 in binary is 1*2<sup>3</sup> + 0*2<sup>2</sup> + 0*2<sup>1</sup> + 1*2<sup>0</sup> = 9 in decimal). The `add ax,bx` instruction will take pairs of particular cells from "ax" and "bx", mix it (in "add" way) together with temporary helper carry flag, and put the resulting bit value back into "ax" cell, continuing from "bit 0" to "bit 15", leaving final carry value in carry flag in flags register. It doesn't need to know the "bit 3" has value 8, that's what the code producing decimal formatting of number will assign it later, when creating output for human.

So if you have `index` with value `0b10`, then the index contains also `2` and `0x02`, it's the same value. How you format it in the source when writing the code or how you format it when you are displaying it to the screen of computer - that's up to you, most of the Assemblers support wide range of possible formatting of values in source, and you can write code to display value in any way you wish.

---

In your question `[si+index]` looks like completely different problem, you are trying to work with "variables" in assembler, but that's not how these work. `index` very likely address into memory, so `mov ax,index` in normal assembler (NASM) will load "ax" with address of memory, not value in index. To load content of memory you should write `mov ax,[index]`. Unfortunately in MASM the compiler works with pseudo variables, turning `mov ax,index` into `mov ax,[index]` automagically, confusing everything. But in case of `[si+index]` it will use the address offset, as expected, because there's no instruction mode capable to execute `[si+[index]]` addressing.

So I'm guessing you are using MASM, and you are confused by the "variable" quirk magic of it. Rather read the Intel docs, instruction reference guide, and learn what is possible to do with instructions.

To fix your problem, load the value of index first into some register, like:

```
mov    bx,[index]     ; bx = 2
mov    al,[si+bx]
```

---

BTW, your problem must be obvious when run in debugger, you should see the instruction in debugger as `mov al,ds:[si+0xSOME_ADDRESS]` instead of `mov al,ds:[si+2]`. When something doesn't work as expected, pay attention to every detail the debugger is displaying (and force it to display everything relevant... does the instruction access memory? Take a peek in memory window on it's content, if there's what you expect there to be. Same with stack values. And of course values in registers...

Comment: There is an exception, with BCD (Binary Coded Decimal) wherein each nibble of the value only counts up to `9` instead of `F`. This has been used where the input is from a device such as a clock, and there are usually processor instructions to adjust these values after performing arithmetic. Apart from that, the various ways of expressing a number are for human comprehension, for example hexadecimal is a more convenient way for humans to read and understand binary format, by grouping the bits in sets of 4.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah, that's why I used "most of the" ... then again you made me wonder, whether BCD instructions work on value-based logic, or bit-pattern matching - with the nibble data set being input I would rather guess it's pattern match, so still not fully aware of numerical value directly? I was thinking more about `div`, but then I got suspicious it may be naively implemented with some bit shifts only. But `shr r,#imm` is probably safe bet as an example of instruction where CPU is well aware of the numerical value encoded in #imm bits.

Comment: I think the `DAA` and `DAS` instructions would need to be aware of the value, since my reference says "if bits 0-3 of AL > 9 ..."